# xlsx table entry displays as a number like 20.41, but the actual is 2/2/1900 12:00:20 PM

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I just get the number value? Whenever I click on it, it just returns to date form and loses the exact value it was before. For the example included, after clicking on it it turns into date format, and then once clicking off it becomes 20.00, losing data.

[image: example]

Comment: It's hard to understand what you've written. This data looks inconsistent.
Answer the following questions one by one:
1. What do you type into a cell?
2. What is the cell format code before entry?
3. What kind of cell look do you want?
4. What does the cell look like after the entry is approved?
5. What is the format code of the cell after the entry?

Comment: I suggest you run `excel /s` to open Excel in Safe Mode to have a check.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your cell format is set to some strange one other than common datetime. Actually time data is stored as a number in excel, and it is the cell format that decides how it is displayed, i.e. as a integer, floating number, date, time, etc. Set it back to the right one and you will get it displayed as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by **`the number value`** nor what you mean by **`get it`**

- The value actually stored in that cell is `33.5002362268519`

  - That value will be **gotten** by any formula that refers to that cell.
- You are seeing this value displayed as `20.41` because the numberformat of that cell is `ss.00` or `s.00`
- If you want to see something else displayed in that cell, merely change the formatting. That will not change the value, only what you see.

  - If you want to see `33.5002362268519` then format as `number` with 13 decimal places
  - If you want to see something else, please be specific as to what you mean by **`number value`**.